# Symfony 2- validation message

Tags: php, symfony

I use symfony validator assert, in my class subscription i have:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="asasass")
 * */
    private $name;
```

Forms:

```
class SubscriptionType extends AbstractType{

    public function getName() {
        return 'Piotrek_subscription';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('name', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'Imię i nazwisko'

                ))
                ->add('email', 'text', array(

                ))
                ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                    'label' => 'Zapisz się'
                ));        }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Piotrek\WitajBundle\Entity\Subscription'
        ));
    }
    }
```

And my controler:

```
$Subscription = new Subscription();

        $form = $this->createForm(new SubscriptionType(), $Subscription);


        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
```

My form don't read the custom validate in comment. Imposes standard , but also do not know where. When I delete comment the ruler is still the same.
So how do you change the text validation?

Comment: Do you have `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` in the definition of your class ?

Comment: Yes, I have the definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You constraint is a server side one, that means when you submit your form the page reloads and you will get the errors. But the message you see is the default HTML5 error message when you try to submit an empty field, because unless you mention otherwise inside your formbuiler, all fields will be rendered as required that's why you get the default hhtml 5 error message

You can do what want using:

Method 1: this will display your custom message "asasasas" after loading the page

set the required option as false

```
builder->add('name', 'text',array('required' => false )
```

Method 2:

Change the default htm5 error message from inside your SubscriptionType , something like this: ( I don't remember it exactly but this could point you to the right path)

```
builder->add('name' ,'text',array(
'attr'=>array('oninvalid'=>"setCustomValidity('bla bla.. ')")
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: In method 1, validation off and dont read my custom validation.

Comment: Method 2 works fine, can get your job done. I've just tested Method 1 and it works like a charm, and displays my custom message I defined in Assert\NotBlank(message="..")

Comment: Method 2 is not my expected result. I wanted to validate occured by adding a comment. 
I don't want to type it rigidly here. Method 1 disables only validation and avoids comment.

Comment: Actually, in most usecases, you dont want to validate in server side a very basic constraint like not blank or not null .. client side validation is preferred that's why, per default, symfony sets the fields you add to your form as required so the validation takes place in client side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like symfony does not read annotations in your code.

Probably you have not enabled annotations in app/config.yml

```
framework:
    validation: { enabled: true, enable_annotations: true }
```